# Scheme - dynamic scope and infinte loop

Tags: scope, lisp, scheme

I read a book about scheme, and it has the next example:

```
(define map
   (lambda (f s)
     (if (null? s)
         '()
          (cons (f (car s))
                (map f (cdr s)))))

(map (lambda (s)
        (set! s '(1 2 3 4))
        'hello)
     '(a b c d))
```

It say that in dynamic scope, we will enter to infinite loop. But why? As I understood, After we apply the application, we arrive to map with

```
f = (lambda (s)
        (set! s '(1 2 3 4))
        'hello)
```

and s= `'(a b c d)`. Now, for the first run, we will apply `f` on `(car '(a b c d)`:

```
((lambda (s)
    (set! s '(1 2 3 4))
    'hello)
 (car '(a b c d)))
```

And now, It change `a` to be `(1 2 3 4)`. And so on.. Where is the loop here?

Comment: This is not totally relevant to the question, but it's incorrect that the call to `f` would "change `a` to be `'(1 2 3 4)`". Scheme passes function parameters by value, so the only thing `(set! s ...)` can change is the value of the variable `s` in the current scope. To replace the `a` in the original list, the function would have to take the whole list as an argument and call `set-car!` on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what the author means is that after `f (car s)` executes, the value of `s` will be `'(1 2 3 4)`, so the value of `(cdr s)` will be `'(2 3 4)`, so you'll call `(map f '(2 3 4))` every time ad infinitum.

However I do not think this is an accurate depiction of dynamic scoping. Since `s` is a parameter to the lambda (and thus not a free variable), only that parameter should be affected by the `set!` and the `s` of the `map` function should be unaffected. So there should be no infinite loop - whether you're using dynamic scoping or not. And if I translate the code to elisp (which is dynamically scoped), the code does in fact not cause an infinite loop. So I'd say your book is wrong in saying there'd be an infinite loop using dynamic scoping.

Comment: Thanks, but I dont get what the author want to say. In dynamוc, the 's' in the map always change. New frame is open every map's call, and the s change. Maybe he wrong, but I didn't get the idea at all.. Thanks.

Comment: It seems like this example is wrong, at least. However, if the function passed to `map` was `(lambda (x) (set! s '(1 2 3 4)) ...`, then you *would* get an infinite loop, because the anonymous function would change the `s` belonging to `map`'s scope. This is kind of a contrived example, but it does show how dynamic scope can leak implementation details like the names of local variables.